# PHP running as apache user, isn't a member of any LDAP groups of which apache is a member

Tags: php, apache, ldap, sssd

In short code executed by PHP as user apache, doesn't seem to have write access to groups which apache is a member of, that apache can write to on a shell.

So I have a user apache on a production server.  If I run `id apache` I see apache as a member of several groups, including `groupa`.  If I `grep apache /etc/groups` I can see that those groups memberships are not defined locally, and are coming from LDAP.

I have a folder `/u/dir` which is owned by `root:groupa` with permissions `g+rws`

If I run `sudo su -s /bin/bash -c "mkdir /u/dir/subdir" apache` it works fine, apache does have permission to create files/folders in `/u/dir`

However if I create and run the following script in PHP it fails with permission denied: `

If I run `id apache` from shell, it shows: `uid=48(apache) gid=123(groupa) groups=123(groupa)`

However if I run the following from PHP I get a different result:-

`<?php echo shell_exec("id");?>`

`uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache)`

Any ideas why PHP (and presumably the Apache/httpd process) don't have all the group memberships that they should, and how I can fix it?

I did do a test, before anyone suggests it; If I add apache to a group in /etc/groups and restart apache, then the above call, shows the new group, but it's not picking up groups that apache is a member of via LDAP (and this server is one of a pool, accessing the remotely mapped /u so I don't want to have to manually duplicate each group locally on each server)

I'll also add that I suspect our servers are getting `id` info from LDAP via `sssd`

Seeing: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/409843/how-to-get-the-supplementary-groups-ids-of-a-process

If I add `<?php echo shell_exec("cat /proc/$$/status"); ?>` I can see that the httpd process hasn't picked up any of the `sssd` groups, just the local ones.

**Edit for Clarity:**

For clarity I should add I tested adding `apache` to local group `(300)testgroup`, then ran `<?php echo shell_exec("id");?>` again:-

`uid=48(apache) gid=48(apache) groups=48(apache),300(testgroup)`

So whilst it's clear it's the core process permissions which matter, for some reason when I startup `httpd` (as `apache:apache`), it is pickup up the local groups which `apache` is a member of and adding those to the subgroup ('Groups' in `/proc/$$/status`), it isn't picking up the groups that `apache` is a member of via sssd.  That's the puzzle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I didn't have a problem at all.  Someone had change the primary group of the apache user to my remote group (groupa in my example), so when apache ran as apache:apache according to the httpd.conf file, it was overwriting that primary group.  As apache wasn't actually a member of groupa other than that, it was appearing to drop the group.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing apples with pears.

The script you are running in the shell as user apache returns the information the shell has for the user.

But when you run your PHP-script it is not only run by the apache user but also by the apache daemon which has a configuration parameter as which user and which group it's subprocesses shall run. And that overwrites the systems information. I'm pretty sure your apaches httpd.conf contains the group and user "apache" somewhere. So the PHP-scripts are executes as user apache and group apache - and only that one group due to the config-setting.

I'm not sure what would happen when you call this PHP-script:

```
<?php
echo shell_exec("/bin/bash id");
```

as that might invoke a new bash-session.

Comment: I did wonder about that, but I can add apache to any groups locally, and those do show up, it's only membership of sssd groups that don't show up. I tried `<?php echo shell_exec("/bin/bash -c id"); ?>` and it returned exactly the same as without the `/bin/bash -c` bit.  I don't think you're on the right path either sadly

Comment: My final comment about /proc/$$/status is indeed comparing applies with the same apples you're referring to, as you're quite right, it's the permissions of the running process which is key.  The question is, why doesn't it pick up the sssd groups are start time, why only the local groups